# A question about convergence in measures

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Denote by $\mathcal{M}(X)$ the set of Borel probability measures of a  space $X$. This set is equipped with weak$^*$ topology defined by the convergence $\mu_n\to \mu$ if and only if $\int \phi d\mu_n\to \int \phi d\mu$ for every continuous map with compact support $\phi:X\to \mathbb{R}$.

Take a sequence $\mu_n\in \mathcal{M}(X)$ converging to $\mu\in\mathcal{M}(X)$, $x\in X$ and $A\subseteq X$. For every $n\in\mathbb{N}$, there is finite set $x\in F_n\subseteq A$ such that $\mu_n(F_n)= \mu_n(A)$.

Is there a finite set $x\in F\subseteq A$ such that $\mu(A)=\mu(F)$?

Please help me to know it.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mu_n$ be uniform distribution on $\{0, 1/n, 2/n,\ldots (n-1)/n\}$ and let $\mu$ be Lebesgue measure on $X=[0,1]$.  If $A$ is such that $\mu(A)>0$, your desired condition is not met.